# Powershell GPO start up script - Uninstall Microsoft Updates

Tags: windows, powershell

I can run this script manually/interactively with an account that has local admin rights and it works perfectly fine, but when I insert it into a GPO start up script or deploy it through SCCM, nothing happens.  It just opens the console window and then closes it - the MS Updates remain installed.

```
$PatchList = @("KB2553154","KB2899519","KB2910902","KB3008923","KB3012176","KB3013126")

function Remove-Update
{
    $HotFixes = Get-HotFix

    foreach ($HotFix in $HotFixes)
    {
        foreach ($KBID in $PatchList)
        {
            if ($KBID -eq $HotFix.HotfixId)
            {
                "Inside first if"
                $KBID = $HotFix.HotfixId.Replace("KB", "") 
                $RemovalCommand = "wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:$KBID /quiet /norestart"
                Write-Host "Removing $KBID from the target."
                Invoke-Expression $RemovalCommand
                break
            }
            if ($KBID -match "All")
            {
                $KBNumber = $HotFix.HotfixId.Replace("KB", "")
                $RemovalCommand = "wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:$KBNumber /quiet /norestart"
                Write-Host "Removing update $KBNumber from the target."
                Invoke-Expression $RemovalCommand
            }           
            if ($KBID -match "Security")
            {
                if ($HotFix.Description -match "Security")
                {           
                    $KBSecurity = $HotFix.HotfixId.Replace("KB", "")
                    $RemovalCommand = "wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:$KBSecurity /quiet /norestart"
                    Write-Host "Removing Security Update $KBSecurity from the target."
                    Invoke-Expression $RemovalCommand
                }
            }   
            while (@(Get-Process wusa -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count -ne 0)
            {
                Start-Sleep 3
                Write-Host "Waiting for update removal to finish ..."
            }
        }
    }
}

Remove-Update
```

I know that with a GPO start up script or SCCM deployment, the account being used to run the script is the system account.  Not sure if that is causing the issue?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you launch the script? Maybe you have to add "-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted"...

Comment: The default policy being RemoteSigned would be my first guess also so jisaak might already have posted the solution. If that doesn't work try running the script with the -noexit switch, so you can read a possible error message.

Comment: @jisaak - I've tried launching the script from our GPO startup script with the -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted switch without success.  I also set the Execution Policy in GPO to "Allow all scripts" and still no luck.

Comment: can you post the execute statement? Also you can check with -noexit whether the script throws any error - as Syberdoor mentioned.

Comment: Once I added the -noexit switch, it worked! Very strange.

Comment: with the command wmic qfe get hotfixid,installedon | findstr MM/DD/YYYY >> c:\list.txt you could find updates from a specific date, how could you add this to your existing script?